# React - Fetch from URL and setState on component load

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I am writing an app using **React Native** and I get weird errors.
I would like to fetch the country of the user on "App load", update the state and then to use the state elsewhere in the component. Sounds simple but I get errors all the time.

For this specific code I get **undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state')**.

What am I doing wrong? How should I do it the right way?

*(I use an API because I do not want to ask for location permissions).*

```
export default function App() {

  state = {
    countryCode: 'US',
  }


  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://ipapi.co/json/')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({ countryCode: data.country_code }));
  }, []);


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      // ...
    </View>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Functional components do not have `this`. There is no such thing as `this.setState` in a functional component. Instead, you have to use `useState`, which, rather than using a property of an instance, uses a plain standalone variable (and a state setter function as another standalone variable) in the function body:

```
export default function App() {
  const [countryCode, setCountryCode] = useState('US');


  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://ipapi.co/json/')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => setCountryCode(data.country_code));
  }, []);


  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      // ...
    </View>
  );
}
```